# VHDL code behaves abnormally after synthesis (I2C)

Tags: vhdl, i2c

First of all, because of company disclosure agreement I am not allowed to post my code thus I will describe the symptoms of the behavior and hopefully it's enough.

I am using the IP for I2C master provided by [Scott Larson on eewiki](https://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10125324) and I use it the same way in the example provided on the page. The difference is that I have several procedures as described in the example

```
WHEN get_data =>                               --state for conducting this transaction
busy_prev <= i2c_busy;                       --capture the value of the previous i2c busy signal
IF(busy_prev = '0' AND i2c_busy = '1') THEN  --i2c busy just went high
    busy_cnt := busy_cnt + 1;                  --counts the times busy has gone from low to high during transaction
END IF;

CASE busy_cnt IS                             --busy_cnt keeps track of which command we are on
    WHEN 0 =>                                  --no command latched in yet
        i2c_ena <= '1';                            --initiate the transaction
        i2c_addr <= slave_addr;                    --set the address of the slave
        i2c_rw <= '0';                             --command 1 is a write
        i2c_data_wr <= data_to_write;              --data to be written

    WHEN 1 =>                                  --1st busy high: command 1 latched, okay to issue command 2
        i2c_rw <= '1';                             --command 2 is a read (addr stays the same)

    WHEN 2 =>                                  --2nd busy high: command 2 latched, okay to issue command 3
        i2c_rw <= '0';                             --command 3 is a write
        i2c_data_wr <= new_data_to_write;          --data to be written
        IF(i2c_busy = '0') THEN                    --indicates data read in command 2 is ready
            data(15 DOWNTO 8) <= i2c_data_rd;       --retrieve data from command 2
        END IF;

    WHEN 3 =>                                  --3rd busy high: command 3 latched, okay to issue command 4
        i2c_rw <= '1';                             --command 4 is read (addr stays the same)

    WHEN 4 =>                                  --4th busy high: command 4 latched, ready to stop
        i2c_ena <= '0';                            --deassert enable to stop transaction after command 4
        IF(i2c_busy = '0') THEN                    --indicates data read in command 4 is ready
            data(7 DOWNTO 0) <= i2c_data_rd;         --retrieve data from command 4
            busy_cnt := 0;                           --reset busy_cnt for next transaction
            state <= home;                           --transaction complete, go to next state in design
        END IF;

    WHEN OTHERS => NULL;

END CASE;
```

For example at the end if the `get_data` instead of going to `home` I go to an initializing case to reset `busy_cnt` and `i2c_ena` and other signals then to another case for writing similar to `get_data`.

**Current Situation**

- The code executes well in simulation, I switch the `i2c_busy` on and off and the behavior is as expected.
- There are no warnings regarding the sensitivity list or any latches. I have a warning that 5 clock signals were `routed using generic routing resource and might suffer from excessive delay and/or skew`

**The Problem**

As I mentioned before the code is divided into several cases similar to `get_data` in the example above and when executing it is stuck in an infinite loop in one of them. And when I change something in the case that is stuck another case before it misbehaves and also stuck in an infinite loop. Even changing a simple signal that has nothing to do with the algorithm (LED output for debugging) in one case might cause a case before it to misbehave.

The infinite loop behavior is also strange and shows state is not set at the end of the case.

Note that I am not using the same way in the example to update state rather I use a separate Process for the state update (`curr_state <= next_state;`) and the `next_state` is the one updated.

**My Speculation**
I assumed that the problem could be because I have to set every output in every case. But even after setting all I could the behavior was similar.

For the sake of completion: The development environment is Lattice Diamond and the FPGA is MachXO2.

Comment: If you have turned the original single-process SM into the more complex 2-process SM that gives you several ways to introduce failures. Double-check things like sensitivity lists and ouputs that were registered but no longer are. The "clock signals routed [strangely]" warnings may be symptoms of this - you might be able to identify their cause. I STRONGLY recommend single process form : what drove you to rewrite as 2-process?

Comment: According to the warning " clock signals were routed using generic routing resource and might suffer from excessive delay and/or skew", means that you have generated some local clocks which was either not intended are you have to buffer them a by clock-buffer. But, this seems not to be a problem within the posted code.

Comment: After reading the code again, the `busy_cnt` looks suspicious, but more context is required.

Comment: @Brian There was no particular reason for writing it in 2-process other than habit and clarity. I will try your solution and reply.
@Martin I did not intentionally generate any of that and I suspected that it has nothing to do with this snippet. The `busy_cnt` was merely the same design provided by the designer in the example (assuming he knows best).

Comment: Is the posted code still part of a clocked process?

Comment: @Martin In my code it's not, the clocked process only updates the `curr_state <= next_state`

Comment: @Brian your guess was correct and the recommendation was a great one. After rewriting in a single process form the problem was solved. I didn't doubt this would be the problem and I spent quiet a while trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code snippet has severe problems, if it's not part of a clocked process anymore according to the comments:

> Me: Is the posted code still part of a clocked process?
>
> mmahdich: @Martin In my code it's not, the clocked process only updates the curr_state <= next_state

If I embed the [code from the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34269301/1) into the following test architecture, then the synthesis compiler XST (from ISE 14.7) reports warnings about latches for the signals `busy_cnt`, `busy_prev` and `data`. The reason that the OP observes no latch warnings may result from further optimizations or interference from the undisclosed code parts. (I have no Lattice Diamond at hand.)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity i2c_test is
  port (
    clk               : in  std_logic;
    i2c_busy          : in  std_logic;
    slave_addr        : in  std_logic;
    data_to_write     : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    new_data_to_write : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    i2c_data_rd       : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    i2c_ena           : out std_logic;
    i2c_addr          : out std_logic;
    i2c_rw            : out std_logic;
    i2c_data_wr       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    data              : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end i2c_test;

architecture rtl of i2c_test is
  type   state_t is (get_data, home);
  signal curr_state : state_t := home;
  signal state      : state_t;          -- next state is named "state" in OP code
  signal busy_prev  : std_logic;
begin  -- rtl
  process (clk)
  begin  -- process
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      curr_state <= state;
    end if;
  end process;

  process(curr_state, busy_prev, i2c_busy, slave_addr, data_to_write, new_data_to_write, i2c_data_rd)
    variable busy_cnt : integer range 0 to 4 := 0;
  begin
    state <= curr_state;              -- next state is named "state" in OP code
    i2c_ena <= '0';
    i2c_addr <= '-';
    i2c_rw  <= '-';
    i2c_data_wr <= (others => '-');
    -- no default assignments for busy_prev and data here, because the usage
    -- below indicates that a register was intended

    case curr_state is
      when home => state <= get_data;

    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Add code from question here
    ---------------------------------------------------------------

    
    end case;
  end process;
end rtl;
```

First of all, the signal for the next state seems to be named `state`.

Then, XST founds latches for the signals `busy_prev` and `data`. I have not added default assignments for these signals in the combinational process because the following assignments in the OP's code indicate that a register was intended:

```
busy_prev <= i2c_busy;              --capture the value of the previous i2c busy signal
data(15 DOWNTO 8) <= i2c_data_rd;   --retrieve data from command 2
data(7 DOWNTO 0) <= i2c_data_rd;    --retrieve data from command 4
```

Finally, one cannot (easily) implement this wait counter without a clocked process:

```
WHEN get_data =>                               --state for conducting this transaction
  IF(busy_prev = '0' AND i2c_busy = '1') THEN  --i2c busy just went high
    busy_cnt := busy_cnt + 1;                  --counts the times busy has gone from low to high during transaction
  END IF;
```

**EDIT**
Synthesizing the above would require flip-flops for `busy_cnt` which is triggered by all signals listed in the process sensitivity list. Of course, a new state will be loaded into the flip-flops only if the condition `(curr_state = get_data and busy_prev = '0' and i2c_busy = '1')` is true. For example, XST synthesizes a latch for this, which is enabled when the condition is true. But then, `busy_cnt` forms a combinational loop during an enabled latch. This synthesized behaviour does not match the VHDL description.

The solution would be to implement the registers `busy_prev`, `data` and `busy_cnt` in the clocked process.

Comment: I see, thank you Martin this was actually a very good explanation. I will attempt to implement the solution as a clocked process as soon as possible. Unfortunately this will take some time since I am on vacation until next year. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Eine schöne Weihnachtszeit und einen guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr!

Comment: I checked it, and the problem seems to be that I separated the process into two. Even the warnings disappeared when I went back to the single process method. Thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated.